# Google analytics events not firing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using the new "universal analytics" package. Everything is working except for event, which are not firing.

```
onClick: "ga('send', 'event', 'ajax_action', 'user_prompt', 'user_classification', 'yes', {'nonInteraction': 1});"
```

That code does not produce an error in the console, but it doesn't trigger an event.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional "value" parameter needs to be an integer. You currently have the string "yes". So if you do need to use that parameter, then you would need to change it:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'ajax_action', 'user_prompt', 'user_classification', 1, {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

Comment: Yes. Also, he should use onclikc="ga(...);" and not onclick with a ":".